# Expanding snippets in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

I'm looking for a way to have short strings expand into code.  For example, if I type `ssf` and hit TAB, I want it to replace with `SELECT * FROM`.  Is there some way to get MySQL Workbench to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In short: no.

And because Stackoverflow wants me to add more characters I added a useless sentence.